# How to get chrome driver working in docker image

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When running tests in a maven project locally, it works using `mvn test`. It works via docker image as well, when I run Java spring boot backend tests.
The problem comes, when I try to run UI tests with chrome driver. I get this error:

Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver
/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My question is, should I install chrome and chromedriver on the docker image or am I missing some dependency?

This is my driver class:

```
WebDriver driver = null;
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

This is relevant part of my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the docker file

```
FROM dockerresource:8123/maven:latest
RUN mkdir -p tests/
WORKDIR tests/
COPY . .
CMD ["run-cron.sh"]
```

This is run-cron.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "<----- Start of tests ----->"
mvn test
echo "<----- End of tests ----->"

# Aways return 0 oterwise in the case of faild test 
# the cron job will fall into and infinint execution loop
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've found a solution. The following works for me, hope I can help someone else!

RUN apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y gnupg wget curl unzip --no-install-recommends && 
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && 
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && 
apt-get update -y && 
apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && 
CHROMEVER=$(google-chrome --product-version | grep -o "[^.]*.[^.]*.[^.]*") && 

DRIVERVER=$(curl -s "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROMEVER") && 

wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$DRIVERVER/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && 

unzip /chromedriver/chromedriver* -d /chromedriver

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please explain your solution?